# How to enable ng-options inside ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I'm trying to use `ng-options` inside `ng-repeat`, but seems I'm missing something bwcause I do not see any values populated into the select control.

Here is the html code:

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <table border="1" style="width:300px">
        <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
        <th>select</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">                        
            <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.age }}</td>               
            <td>
            <select ng-model="person.chosenNumber" ng-options="suggestion.number as suggestion.destination for suggestion in person.suggestedPhones"></select>
            <button ng-click="showSelected()">Ok</button>
            </td>
        </tr>        
    </table>
</div>
```

Js code:

```
var testModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

function testCtrl($scope) {                      

$scope.persons = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'omer', 'age': 35,  'suggestedPhones': {'destination': 'home', 'number': '0544317259'} },
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'noam', 'age': 32, 'suggestedPhones': {'destination': 'home', 'number': '036024607'} },
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'dafna', 'age': 28, 'suggestedPhones': {'destination': 'home', 'number': '0522318779'} }
]

$scope.showSelected = function () {
    alert(1);       
}
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvpdh/)

Answer (score 4):

Either the `suggestedPhones` is wrong (should be array) or you should use the `label for (key , value) in object` ([ref](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect)) variant of `ng-options`. Try the following, if it is indeed what you want:

```
$scope.persons = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'omer', 'age': 35,  'suggestedPhones': [{'destination': 'home', 'number': '0544317259'}] },
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'noam', 'age': 32, 'suggestedPhones': [{'destination': 'home', 'number': '036024607'}] },
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'dafna', 'age': 28, 'suggestedPhones': [{'destination': 'home', 'number': '0522318779'}] }
]
```

(The `suggestedPhones` have become arrays.)

---

(UPDATE RELEVANT TO COMMENT) Getting the selected person and phone data is as simple as:

```
<button ng-click="showSelected(person)">Ok</button>
```

And in the JS:

```
$scope.showSelected = function (person) {
    console.log(person);        
}
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/C5jK9/

Comment: Thank you. How can I retrieve the chosen value from the java script ?

Comment: I am not sure which value exactly do you want. Could you give a (detailed) example, and we will work it out?

Comment: Once the user chooses the value in the select control and presses the ok button I wish to retrieve all the values (id, name, age and the one in the select control) in the js side and do something (for example do an ajax call). what is the best practice for doing that? pass the showSelected function the person object?

Comment: in your scope, put something like $scope.bag = {personChosenNumber:false} and in your select model, put bag.personChosenNumber as ng-model name.. now, the selected value will be available in the bag.personChosenNumber in scope.  Right now your chosen value is buried under persons

Comment: Another one, how can I set the default index for the select control ?

Comment: You initialize the object as: `{'id': 1, 'name': 'omer',...,'chosenNumber':'0544317259'}`

Comment: I did that and it works, but i don't understand how... the ng-model is set to: "person.chosenNumber" while the field you suggested to change ('number') to 'chosenNumber' is a part of the suggestedPhones member of person and not a direct member of the person object. can you please explain how this works? thanks

Comment: so to clarify, this is the persons form the js part:
$scope.persons = [
     {'id': 1, 'name': 'omer', 'age': 35,  'suggestedPhones': [{'destination': 'home', 'chosenNumber': '0544317259'}] },
     {'id': 2, 'name': 'noam', 'age': 32, 'suggestedPhones': [{'destination': 'office', 'chosenNumber': '036024607'}] },
     {'id': 3, 'name': 'dafna', 'age': 28, 'suggestedPhones': [{'destination': 'work', 'chosenNumber': '0522318779'}] }
 ]

this is the html:
del="person.chosenNumber" ng-options="suggestion.number as suggestion.destination for suggestion in person.suggestedPhones"></select>

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <table border="1" style="width:300px">
        <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
        <th>select</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">                        
            <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.age }}</td>               
            <td>
            <select ng-model="person.chosenNumber" ng-options="suggestion.number as suggestion.destination for suggestion in person.suggestedPhones"></select>
            <button ng-click="showSelected($index)">Ok</button>
            </td>
        </tr>        
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var testModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

function testCtrl($scope) {                      

$scope.persons = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'omer', 'age': 35,  'suggestedPhones': {'destination': 'home', 'number': '0544317259'} },
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'noam', 'age': 32, 'suggestedPhones': {'destination': 'home', 'number': '036024607'} },
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'dafna', 'age': 28, 'suggestedPhones': {'destination': 'home', 'number': '0522318779'} }
]

$scope.showSelected = function (data) {
    alert($scope.persons[data].chosenNumber);       
}
```